# aiml - wildcards between pattern terms

Tags: pattern-matching, aiml

Is it possible to use wild cards between terms in a pattern? for example, if I want to answer the question, "How much are overdue fines on my books?" is there a way to use a wild card between the terms "overdue" and "books?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Do something like:

```
<category>
<pattern>How much are overdue * on my books?</pattern>
<template><srai>YOUR <star/> IS</srai></template>
</category>

<category>
<pattern>YOUR FINE IS</pattern>
<template>Vote me up!</template>
</category

<category>
<pattern>YOUR STAMPS IS</pattern>
<template>20 pounds. Pay for this please.</template>
</category>
```

Comment: But, remember that the pattern must be CAPS and no punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough brownie points to respond to Bravax's answer, but to add to the solution by addressing the topic of the sentence used. In Engrish, one would normally say, "How much are Overdue Fines on my books?"; "fines" is the Star here, but the 'Cat is looking for "fine", so the 'Cat won't see it.

Consider changing the 'Cat's 2nd pattern from "your fine is", to "your fines are". The rest kind of flows along.